# iOS Async Task Issue When Returning Firebase Usernames

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase-authentication

I'm so close to accomplishing this part of my project. I've learned a lot, but just can't see, to wrap this up. What I am trying to do is essentially check if an email address is already being used by another user. To accomplish this, I am using this code:

```
func emailCheck(input : String, result:(canRegister: Bool?) -> Void){
    var canRegister : Bool?
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(input, password: " "){(user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if(error?.code == 17009){
                print("Wrong Password")
                canRegister = false
            }else if(error?.code == 17011){
                print("Unknown User")
                canRegister = true
            }else{
                canRegister = false
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

This whole `Async` thing is only 6 hours old to me, so if you have any suggestions please let me know. But this function is then called when a button is pressed, just by doing this:

```
print(emailCheck(emailTxt.text!){(canRegister : Bool?) -> Void in})
```

For some reason, this is returning empty, not `true`, `false` or even `nil`. It just returns `()` However it does return `Wrong Password` when I do pass in the right password, not quite sure if thats relevant. Can anybody lend a hand with this? Thanks everybody!

**Added Info**
After suggestions, the code and the reference to the code now looks like this: (Only included important parts)

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
@IBAction func nextScreen(sender: UIButton) {
 emailCheck(emailTxt.text!) { isValid in
                if isValid {
                    print("Valid!")
                } else {
                    print("Invalid!")
                }
            }
}
func emailCheck(input: String, callback: (isValid: Bool) -> Void) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(input, password: "") { (user, error) in
        var canRegister = false

        if error != nil {
            if (error?.code == 17009) {
                //wrong password error
            } else if(error?.code == 17011) {
                //email doesn't exist
                canRegister = true
            }
        }

        callback(isValid: canRegister)
    }
}
```

The though process behind this is that if the code returned is that the user doesn't exists, then the email account is open to be resisted with, thus allowing  `canRegister`, otherwise, if the empty password passed into it is incorrect, then we know that the account exists and is therefore not open to be registered using. Currently, `canRegister` returns the value equal to whatever it is defined as here:

```
var canRegister = false
```

Back in the function call.

Comment: The updated code looks correct to me. It seems like, for some reason, you aren't getting an error code 17011 back from Firebase. Digging into their docs, I'm thinking their API isn't behaving the way you may expect. According to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth_errors), the `FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound` error (which matches the 17011 code you used) _"Indicates the user account was not found. This could happen if the user account has been deleted."_ It's not clear to me if that is the only case where that error is thrown...

Comment: In any case, getting more to the root of what you are trying to do...It looks to me like you may be trying to handle something they handle for you. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth.html#aeaee7fcef878990954f8e72f7278cd7d) for the `createUserWithEmail` method say it can throw a `FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse` error, which it seems like that is what you are trying to handle yourself. Why not just try creating it and handle this error, instead?

Comment: @dbburgess You know what it was? I was missing a space in this line: `...signInWithEmail(input, password: " ") ...` Because `password` had no space the firebase wasn't reading it as an empty password, rather probably more like a `nil`, which then wouldn't throw an error. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Thanks again for your amazing answer, hopefully others struggling with this will up vote it as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the return value of `emailCheck`, which isn't quite what you want. Async just means that portion of code will be run at some later time. Consider this simple function:

```
func emailCheck(input: String) -> Bool {
  var valid = true

  if input.characters.count == 0 {
    valid = false
  }

  return valid
}
```

This simply checks if an email has more than zero characters. It could be simplified significantly, but I've made it a bit more verbose to illustrate the differences. To use it, you'd simply do something like this:

```
let isValid = emailCheck("me@example.com")

if isValid {
    print("Valid!")
} else {
    print("Invalid!")
}
```

If we want the method to be able to do work asynchronously, we'd provide it a callback. A callback is just a function that can be called to let us know what the results were, instead of them being returned directly by the function. Here is what that looks like:

```
func emailCheck(input: String, callback: (isValid: Bool) -> Void) {
    var valid = true

    if input.characters.count == 0 {
        valid = false
    }

    callback(isValid: valid)
}

func callback(isValid: Bool) {
    if isValid {
        print("Valid!")
    } else {
        print("Invalid!")
    }
}

emailCheck("me@example.com", callback: callback)
```

Note that `emailCheck` no longer *returns* a value, but actually executes the callback method with the result. This isn't truly asynchronous yet, because the callback is executed right away, but it lets us do asynchronous things if we want to.

Swift has some neat syntactical sugar for passing callbacks as the last parameter without declaring them explicitly like I did above. This is what you are using for Firebase's `signInWithEmail` method. Using that in this code, it looks like this:

```
emailCheck("me@example.com") { isValid in
    if isValid {
        print("Valid!")
    } else {
        print("Invalid!")
    }
}
```

It does exactly the same thing, but I think it looks a little nicer in this case. So now we have a good setup that can check the email, and some code that can run later once we know if the email is valid or not. Putting it all together:

```
func emailCheck(input: String, callback: (isValid: Bool) -> Void) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(input, password: " ") { (user, error) in
        var canRegister = false

        if error != nil {
            if (error?.code == 17009) {
                print("Wrong Password")
            } else if(error?.code == 17011) {
                print("Unknown User")
                canRegister = true
            }
        }

        callback(isValid: canRegister)
    }
}


var availableEmail = false

emailCheck("me@example.com") { isValid in
    if isValid {
        print("Valid!")
    } else {
        print("Invalid!")
    }

    availableEmail = isValid
    // This prints **second**, and should print `true`, if `isValid` was true.
    print(availableEmail)
}

// This prints **first**, and should print `false`, because the callback likely has not run yet.
print(availableEmail)
```

**Edit:** See the `print` code / comments above that illustrate how a variable is not updated right away when you use a callback method.

**Additional edit:** Another way to structure it, using another function for clarity:

```
emailCheck("me@example.com") { isValid in
    if isValid {
        print("Valid!")
    } else {
        print("Invalid!")
    }

    self.emailCheckComplete(isValid)
}

func emailCheckComplete(availableEmail: Bool) {
    // This is the same as above, but perhaps helps you follow the flow.
    print(availableEmail)
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, `isValid` is type `Bool`, so you could do `callback(isValid: true)`, but what if the email is taken? You'd want to use false. That's why I used `canRegister`, which is also a `Bool` and is set to true / or false accordingly.

Comment: In my example, `emailCheck` doesn't return _any_ value, maybe I'm not understanding what you mean though.

Comment: Can you edit your post with what you've changed based on my example? It'd be helpful to see the updated code to understand what you mean.

Comment: No, `availableEmail` is being updated...But you are probably using it _outside_ the scope of the callback method. In which case, you are using it _before_ it is updated. Understanding _when_ each section of code runs is a critical, and easy to get wrong when you are first learning. Remember, the callback is only ran _at some point in the future_. Any code outside of it is ran _immediately_. It's difficult to demonstrate in comments due to restricted formatting, see my answer edits for some additional details.

Comment: The callback _is_ a `completion:` block. I just chose to name it `callback:`, but you could name it `completion:`. It's just semantics. But only the code inside of there will have access to the updated values. You could call a function from within that block, which I find can help clarify the way the code is flowing. See additional edits.

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. The downside of anything async. :) It is very inconvenient and you have to work a little bit to make the code nice, readable, and understandable. It gets easier the more you do it though.

Comment: So so far I've gone from the callback from your solution to another function that basically gets true and false for each condition, but again I think I'm going to have to run another callback to yet another function, which will be testing all of the various combinations of the true and false, which will probably need another callback and then MAYBE, just MAYBE it will work as it should. Can't get much easier than `true` or `false` but yet iOS still needs time to process it. Amazing

Comment: would trying to present a `UIAlertView` from within a callback of this function require me to register it differently with the `rootViewController`? I can't seem to get them to appear because the views that are trying to show are not part of the window hierarchy

Comment: It's not that iOS needs time to process `true` or `false`, but that Firebase has to go talk to it's server to know whether the answer is `true` or `false`. That is what takes time. Once you have the answer, iOS can do whatever with it in real-time.

Comment: As for the alert view, I don't think you should have to do anything radically different.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense then. Thank you!